# About a definition of "rank" of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, determinant, convex-optimization

I am familiar with the definition of rank of a matrix as either (1) the maximal number of linearly independent rows or columns or (2) as the dimension of the image of the matrix.

Another alternative definition is that given a $m \times n$ matrix $M$, $rank(M) = min\{ r \vert \forall i \in \{1,2..,m\}, j \in \{1,2,..,n\} \exists v_i , w_j \in \mathbb{R}^r ,  M_{ij} = v_i^T w_j  \}$

- Can someone help show that the above rank means the usual thing?
- Given a $M$ how does one find these needed $m+n$, $v$ and $w$ vectors?

Comment: This alternate "definition" is not correct.  If $r = 1$, then you can choose $v_i = 1$ and $w_j = M_{ij}$ and the equation would hold, so the rank of any matrix by this "definition" would be 1 (except when it could be $0$).

Comment: @DerekElkins It looks like there is something strange with the quantifier order, sure, but the idea is that you pick a $v_i$ for each $i$, a $w_j$ for each $j$, and this may be done in such a way that $M_{ij}=v_i^Tw_j$ for all $i,j$ in their respective range.

Answer (score 1):

$rank(M) = \min\{r|\exists V \in L(m,r), W \in L(n,r). M = V^TW \}$ where $L(m,n)$ is the space of $n\times m$ matrices is my rewriting of the (intended) meaning of your definition.  You should verify that it is equivalent.  I think this definition (particularly compared to your definition of rank as the dimension of the image) makes it much easier to answer your first question.  In particular, the matrix $W$ should be pretty clear.  As to your second question, how do you find the image of a matrix?  Also, if $W$ is clear to you, you can consider that $M^T = W^TV$, so the $V$ matrix can be found in the same way as the $W$ matrix.

Comment: Is $W$ the map that is mapping $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the $Image(M)$? (where $r = dim(Im(W))$) So the $w_j$s are $r$ linearly independent vectors chosen inside $\mathbb{R}^n$ to span $Im(M)$? But how does one show the minimality condition?

Comment: Yes, that would be a valid and natural choice for $W$.  The image of a function in general, is, by definition, the smallest set containing the outputs of the function.  To map to anything smaller would necessarily require discarding information.  If you choose some $W$ with $dim(Im(W)) < r$ then it must be the case that $Wx = Wy$ when $Mx \neq My$ for some vectors $x$ and $y$.

Comment: But that is only proving in a certain class of $W$. One needs to show that no $<r$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can serve as the image of $W$.

Comment: The last sentence in my previous comment covered the case where $dim(Im(W)) < r = dim(Im(M))$.  It was not restricted to a "certain class" of $W$ (or I don't understand what "class" you think it is restricted to).  What *does* still need to be shown is that there actually exists a $V$ such that $V^T W = M$ for at least one choice of $W$ with $dim(Im(W)) = r$. (There actually exists such a $V$ for any choice.)

Comment: I mean your argument will work only for ruling out those Ws whose image space is a subspace of $Im(M)$. Will it work to rule out arbitrary small Ws? Can't we always use $V$ to be the projection map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $Im(M)$?

Comment: Nothing says the image of $W$ needs to be a subset of the image of $M$.